# Registration e-mails are evaluated as spam by google

Tags: email, gmail, spam

When users register on my web site they get a confirmation email so that thay could activate their account. 
However, a lot of gmail users get those mails as spam. It's a bit disturbing.

Someone knows how to fix this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Check your domain against [blacklists](http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx), add [DKIM](http://www.dkim.org/), and also consider adding [SPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework).  The last two help validate your e-mail that it came from your domain.

[Here are Google's instructions](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126?hl=en) to help with sending mail to gmail users.

Comment: A lot of good information here ! thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Look for the spam report in the header of the email. I don't know for gmail but in Outlook you have to right click on the message and choose "message option" or something similar (mine is not in english so it might be something else)

Here's an exemple from a mail I sent.

X-Spam-Report:

```
* -1.0 ALL_TRUSTED Passed through trusted hosts only via SMTP
*  0.0 WEIRD_PORT URI: Uses non-standard port number for HTTP
*  1.6 HTML_IMAGE_ONLY_12 BODY: HTML: images with 800-1200 bytes of words
*  0.0 HTML_MESSAGE BODY: HTML included in message
*  0.0 T_OBFU_PDF_ATTACH BODY: PDF attachment with generic MIME type
*  1.1 MIME_HTML_ONLY BODY: Message only has text/html MIME parts
*  0.0 T_REMOTE_IMAGE Message contains an external image
```

Each number at the left-hand side add up to your final score, you want to lower this score in order to avoid been taged as SPAM. Search for each non 0 report on google, you will find the way to avoid each one of them.

Comment: nice ! I'm going to find this out ! big thanks man